# Como adicionar <li> dinamicamente no <ul> com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, collection

Estou trazendo notificações do backend e preciso adicionar dinamicamente o caminho para elas, como faço para adicionar um `<li>` a cada elemento da resposta?

*JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/tasks/not-assign",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (res) {
        for(var i = 0; i<res.length; i++) {
            $('#taskItem').html(res[i].title);
            var a = document.getElementById('taskItem'); //or grab it by tagname etc
            a.href = "/tasks/detail/" + res[i].id;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false" style="color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="numberTask" class="badge"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a id="taskItem"></a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Do jeito que está ele traz apenas o último item da collection, preciso adicionar as `<li>` dinamicamente.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você provavelmente tem um `<ul>` na sua página, defina um ID para ela ou uma CLASSE caso não tenha. E no `success` do AJAX coloque o código abaixo dentro do `for`:

```
$('#id-do-ul').append('<li><a href="/tasks/detail/'+res[i].id'">'+res[i].title+'</a></li>');
```

Ou pode fazer usando o `each()`:

```
var box = $('#id-do-ul');
success: function(res){
    $.each(res, function(i, v){
        box.append('<li><a href="/tasks/detail/'+i'">'+v.title+'</a></li>');
    })
}
```

Comment: Excelente o uso do `$.each`

Answer (score 5):

Parece-me que você está sempre apagando o conteúdo de `#taskItem` e preenchendo-o com o novo valor, de modo que você sempre tem apenas o último apresentado pelo `loop`. Basicamente, o método [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) do jQuery seta o conteúdo de um seletor, independente do que já havia previamente nele. Uma solução seria usar o médoto [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), que vai adicionando elementos ao final de uma lista. Seu código pode ser reescrito como

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/tasks/not-assign",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (res) {
    for(var i = 0; i<res.length; i++) {
      var _li = "<li><a class='taskItem' href='/tasks/detail/" + res[i].id"'>" + res[i].title + "</li>";
      $(".dropdown-menu").append(_li);
    }
  }
});
```

Perceba a mudança de `ID` para `class` na tag `<a>`. Nunca é demais ser semanticamente correto.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a propriedade .appendTo

`$('<li />', {html: "Meu texto", href: "/tasks/detail/"}).appendTo('ul.dropdown-menu')`

Qualquer duvida siga o exemplo : https://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/fxmngLwd/